# Laravel Backpack custom create page with passed in value

Tags: php, laravel-backpack

so I'm trying to figure out how to do a custom create page in Laravel Backpack that would allow me to pass a value in through the URL (think create?folderId=1). What I'm trying to do is akin to [this](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/91), however, my create page doesn't need to look any different, I just need to use the value passed through the URL in the store function. I think this should be doable using the same idea as [this tut](https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud), however, I'm not sure how to make a child controller that would affect the create page, not the main crud?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom Create page for each Controllers.Your Controller calls the Create page from the vendor folder. To create your own one,

1. Copy the `create.blade.php` file from your-`project/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/` to a path `your-project/resources/views/vendor/backpack/base`

You can rename the new file as your wish,say `new_create.blade.php`

2. In `YourCrudController`, inside `public function setup()` add  line `$this->crud->setCreateView('vendor.backpack.base.new_create');`

Your controller now calls this new Create page. And you can customize the `new_create.blade.php` as your wish.

Comment: Thank you so much, same we can do with 
$this->crud->setListView('vendor.backpack.crud.new_create'); .